# Derivative method is changing original list when it should be returning newList

Tags: java, linked-list

I have an assignment where I am manipulating polynomials using linked lists. One portion of the assignment is to take the first, second and third derivatives of a polynomial. All my methods work individually. However, after running the first derivative method, it changes original input list to what the first derivative is–something I do not want.

Here is my method:

```
public ObjectList derivative(ObjectList list1) {
    newList = new ObjectList();
    ObjectListNode p = list1.getFirstNode();
    while (p != null) {
        Term t1 = (Term) p.getInfo();
        if (t1.getExp() == 0) {
            t1.setCoeff(0);
            attach(0,0);
            p = p.getNext();
        }
        else {
            t1.setCoeff(t1.getCoeff()*t1.getExp());
            t1.setExp(t1.getExp() - 1);
            attach(t1.getCoeff(), t1.getExp());
            p = p.getNext();
        }
    }
    return newList;
}
```

As you can see, the return for the derivative method is `newList`. However, the method is changing the original list.

In my main, I have something like this:

```
ObjectList poly1;

System.out.println("\nEnter a polynomial (for derivatives): ");
poly1 = p.getPolynomial();

System.out.println("First derivative: ");
p.displayPoly(p.derivative(poly1));

System.out.println("\nTest:");
p.displayPoly(poly1);
```

`poly1` ends up changing.

My input into the console I have been using is : `3x^4+2x^3+1x^2-1x^1+8x^0`

This is probably an extremely simple mistake, but for some reason I cannot catch it. Thanks for any help, I appreciate it!

EDIT: The attach method in the derivative method:

```
private void attach (int coeff, int exp) {
    Term t = new Term (coeff, exp);
    newList.addLast(t);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only initializing the `newList` instance (with `newList = new ObjectList()`) without putting anything in it, and you are updating the terms of the input list `list1`.

You didn't post the code of `ObjectList` and `ObjectListNode`, so I can't say the exact methods you should call in order to add nodes to `newList`, but you should add a new node to `newList` for each node of the input list, initialize it to contain a copy of the respective Term of the input list, and update the Term of the newList instead of the Term of the input list.

EDIT :

You don't pass `newList` to `attach`, so the list you are adding terms to is not the same list you initialize in the `derivative` method. In addition, you shouldn't call `setCoeff` and `setExp` on the terms of the input list, since you don't want to change it.

Therefore you should replace :

```
        t1.setCoeff(0);
        attach(0,0);
```

with :

```
        attach(0,0);
```

And replace :

```
        t1.setCoeff(t1.getCoeff()*t1.getExp());
        t1.setExp(t1.getExp() - 1);
        attach(t1.getCoeff(), t1.getExp());
```

with :

```
        attach(t1.getCoeff()*t1.getExp(), t1.getExp() - 1);
```

However, if you want to update the `newList` created in the `derivative` method, you should either pass the newList to the attach method, or cancel the attach method and move its content to the derivative method :

```
public ObjectList derivative(ObjectList list1) {
    newList = new ObjectList();
    ObjectListNode p = list1.getFirstNode();
    while (p != null) {
        Term t1 = (Term) p.getInfo();
        if (t1.getExp() == 0) {
            Term t = new Term (0,0);
            newList.addLast(t);
            p = p.getNext();
        }
        else {
            Term t = new Term (t1.getCoeff()*t1.getExp(), t1.getExp() - 1);
            newList.addLast(t);
            p = p.getNext();
        }
    }
    return newList;
}
```

Comment: That is what is happening. Each the attach method adds the coeff and exp as new nodes. Although, I did not post the code. Let me post it right now. @Eran